# clickon/'tap'/'touchstart'/'click' event that works on all devices and browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

Hi I am looking for a clickon/'tap'/'touchstart'/'click'

That works on all devices,

Some of these are working on Android and some of then are working on IOS, but is there one the is working for all?

the the moment I got 3 different function to cover what I think is most of them,

```
$('.tel').on('tap',function( event ) {}
$('.tel').on('touchstart' ,function( event ) {}
$('.tel').on('click' ,function( event ) {}
```

is there on that can work for all? That have been properly tested?

Comment: `touchstart` and `tap` are not the same. It can be compared with `mousedown` and `click`. Anyway, if you want to do that in one line, you can simply type `$('.tel').on('tap touchstart click',function( event ) {});`. Also, there are some libraries to help with mobile devices. Personally I have used a mini library called [quojs](https://github.com/soyjavi/quojs).

Comment: Thank you so much for the library, I will take a look at that and see what I can take from it

Answer (score 0):

Cool thing is that you can use all 3 in one shot!

```
$('.tel').on('tap touchstart click',function( event ) {}
```

Another option for you is to detect what type of event you need to be listening to before things get started.

```
var CLICK = (navigator.userAgent.match(/ios|android|ipad/i) ? 'touchstart' : 'click' )
```

this will check if the useragent matches a mobile UA and if so assign CLICK to `touchstart` or `click`

in your listener:

```
$('.tel').on(CLICK,function( event ) {}
```

Comment: The page that I am working on is down at the moment. But I believe that I tried this and when I did the function ran two times for 'tap' and 'click'. But I will take a look at this again to make sure I am not misinforming anyone reading this

Comment: you should be able to get away with touchstart and click actually vs the tap. That's outdated I believe. OR see my updated answer for another solution.